# If $V$ the set of values of adherences of $(x_{n})$ then $V=\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}{F_{k}}$

Tags: metric-spaces

> A point  $a$ in a metric space $M$ is called a value of adherence of sequence $(x_{n})$ in $M$, when $a$ is a limit of the one subsequence of $(x_{n})$. Let $V$ the set of values of adherences of $(x_{n})$ and, for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $F_{k}$ the adherence of set $\{x_{n};n\geq k\}$. Show that $V=\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}{F_{k}}$ and conclude that $V$ is a closed subset of M.

How I can prove that X is closed? I need help. Regards

Comment: Is it not true that $F_1 = V$?

Comment: Moreover, the set of all sub-sequential limits is a closed set. This is essentially the same thing. Are you missing hypotheses perhaps?

Comment: mmm , I wrote the problem as it is in my book.

Comment: "the set of all sub-sequential limits is a closed set", this is what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you must prove this. That's in essence what you're asked to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sketch of proof that the set of sub-sequential limits is a closed set:

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence. Let $E^{*}$ be the set of all sub-sequential limits of $\{x_n\}$. We shall show $E^{*}$ contains its limit points. Let $a \in \overline{E^{*}}$. Then, there exists a sequence of elements of $E^{*}$ converging to $a$.

But there is a sequence of elements converging to each element of $E^{*}$. Ergo, we can find a subsequence that converges to $a$.

Do you need a hint to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I think that i could manage a way to show that $V$ is a closed subset.

Denote by $A^{C}$ the complementary set of $A$ in $M$. Since you have proven that $V=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}{F_{k}}$, by De Morgan law it follows that:
$$V^C=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}{F_{k}}^C$$
Since every $F_k$ is closed, it is true that $F_{k}^C$ is open. Since any arbitrary union of open sets is open, we conclude that $V^C$ is an open set. Therefore, $V$ must be a closed subset of $M$.